# Cannot iterate using for-in javascript

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

I am trying to display images into thumbnails for my image gallery by using `for...in` loop but it is only able to display one image. I am still a beginner in javascript, so my understanding of for loops is still not good.  Where did I go wrong?

sample array:

```
["http://tos-staging-web-server-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/9/catalogue/apples_in_season.png",
 "http://tos-staging-web-server-s3.s3.amazonaws.com/9/catalogue/apples_in_season.png"]
```

`for...in` loop:

```
for(var thumb in thumbnails) {
    $('.thumbnail img').attr({"src":[thumbnails[thumb]]});
}
```

Comment: `thumb` is already the value, `$('.thumbnail img').attr({"src":thumb});`

Comment: @Tushar: No, `thumb` is the key: `0`, then `1`. You need ES6 `for (var thumb of thumbnail)` for what you are saying. OP, `src` should not be an array: `attr({"src": thumbnails[thumb] })`. Also, you're setting *all* the thumbnail images to one value, then another, which is probably not what you want (then again, your whole array has the same value...)

Comment: @Tushar it doesnt work i get a 404 error, isn't `thumb` the key?

Comment: for-in should only be used for iterating over the keys and values of an object. Use a standard for loop or Array.prototype.forEach if you can use ES6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, your loop is perfectly fine. You do iterate over all the URLs in your array, but for each URL you set it as `src` for the same thumbnail `img`, effectively overwriting it each time.

It is hard to help you fix it, because I don't know your exact layout and requirements, but you effectively either need to create a set of `img`s for thumbnails (as opposed to just one `img`, which seems to be the case now), and set their `src`s in order, or create brand new `img` each time and append it to some parent container, like so:

```
for(var thumb in thumbnails) {
    $(<some container>).append($('<img>').attr({"src":[thumbnails[thumb]]}));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `for .. in` for iterating through arrays. [**Why?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea)
Use `Array.prototype.forEach` instead.

Also, if you want to create an element using jQuery, then use another syntax:

```
thumbnails.forEach(function(thumb) {
    $("<img/>").attr('src', thumb).appendTo(container);
});
```

Working example:

```js
var thumbnails = [
'https://blog.stackoverflow.com/images/wordpress/stackoverflow-logo-alt2-300.png', 
'http://letscode.ghost.io/content/images/2015/09/stackoverflow.png',
'https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq8EX.png'];

thumbnails.forEach(function(thumb) {
  $("<img/>").attr('src', thumb).appendTo('body');
});
```

```css
img {
  height: 100px;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```